# GNUplot script that works with tab seperated .txt but not with .csv even when the datafile separater is changed

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I have a GNUplot script that works perfectly with tab separated data, but my data comes in .csv files and it would be really handy to read them direct, any ideas?

Here is a sample of data in comma seprated.csv format, the other is exactly the same but in a .txt and obviously tab by a comma rather than a tab

```
HEADER
HEADER

Timestamp,Date,Time,Value,Units
1413867843,21/10/2014,05:04:03,0.053,µA
1413867243,21/10/2014,04:54:03,0.091,µA
1413866643,21/10/2014,04:44:03,0.084,µA
1413866043,21/10/2014,04:34:03,20.000,µA
1413846241,20/10/2014,23:04:01,0.041,µA
1413845641,20/10/2014,22:54:01,0.056,µA
1413845041,20/10/2014,22:44:01,0.123,µA
1413844441,20/10/2014,22:34:01,20.000,µA
1413824638,20/10/2014,17:03:58,0.075,µA
1413824038,20/10/2014,16:53:58,0.073,µA
1413823438,20/10/2014,16:43:58,0.103,µA
1413822838,20/10/2014,16:33:58,20.000,µA
```

Here is the problematic GNUPlot script I use

## CSV MIN

```
#!/gnuplot
set terminal pdf enhanced font "sans,6"

#Filename
set output "BIOSENSE GRAPH TEMPLATE.pdf"
set size ratio 0.71 
set pointsize 0.1

set datafile separator ","


#DATA FILES
plot 'ACT.csv'  using 1:4 every::6 title 'Active'  with points pt 5 lc rgb 'red'  axes x1y1
```

And finally this is the error message I get from GNUplot

line 15: x range is invalid

Any help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I am just wondering if it is the micro-amp symbol at the end of the lines -  that is a non-ASCII character and it may not be expected in a `CSV` whereas you may get away with it in a `TXT` file

Comment: Thats an interesting thought Mark, I shall give it a try

Comment: Fair point Cristoph I shall edit it shortly

Comment: I tired with a sample of data with micro deleted but it didn't seem to fix the problem,

Comment: Unfortunately, this still isn't a minimal example, because you have three files in your script, but only a single one you showed. Assuming, that the file `ACT.csv` (and therefore removing the other two plot lines), it works fine for me with versions 4.2.6, 4.6.5 and 5.0. But I don't know if there are some differences between the three files, or if the error comes from somewhere else. So please provide a single script and a single data file, which can be run on their own by someone else and which do show this problem!

Comment: It runs fine for me on OSX with gnuplot v5.0 if I delete references to the other 2 data files.

Comment: the other 2 files are identical other than values., I will edit the question shortly, are you both on OSX? im on version 4.6.6 on windows, if its working for you in OSX it must be a windows thing?

Comment: No, I did the tests on Windows, also 4.6.6 works fine :). Does the error also appear if you use `skip` instead of `every` to skip the header? I.e. with the command `plot 'ACT.csv'  using 1:4 skip 7`. Does the error also appear if you remove the header lines entirely?

Comment: I've just tried both of those things, still get the same error, its so weird that it works in one format and not the other, and now it seems to work for other people?

Comment: Last tries: Does it also happen if you copy&paste the data file from your question into a newly created file? Does your data file contain a BOM (byte-order mark)? Or can you upload your unchanged data file somewhere? Maybe it contains some weird characters which get lost when posting the content via stackoverflow.

Comment: OK, I just tried using a script using a .txt file for my data, but kept the data as comma seperated, and I got the same error, so im thinking its something to do with     set datafile separator ","      what that could be I have no idea

Comment: The extension of your data file is completely irrelevant for gnuplot, its just part of the name! You could also name your file `foo.bar`.

Comment: Learn something new everyday, I assumed it was recorded differently or something, I dunno, I'm just a chemist

Comment: Christoph that is quite possible, Ill try copying from stack and see if that works for me, I'll ask the technical guys about BOM, unfortunately I can't upload the file. Atm I am just using excel to convert the .csv to tab separated .txt and that works